# AWS Lex - Clear Session

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

Is there a way to clear/close a session in AWS Lex through the API call (boto3).

Say, the user is conversing with Lex bot which serves multiple intents. At some point, the user gives a negative answer to a prompt from the bot to abort the current intent. I am able to recognize that the user wants to talk about some other intent of the bot. I want a way to clear the current session through API call (Boto3) so that the bot is not expecting input for the closed intent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no published API call for resetting the slot data and attributes of a Lex session, but you can always switch to a brand-new session.  This is what the Console does when you click on "Clear chat history" in the "Test bot" interface.  The abandoned session will [time out in 5 min by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/context-mgmt.html#context-mgmt-session-timeout).

You can open a new session by submitting a new [userId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html#API_runtime_PostText_RequestSyntax) in the next call to PostText.  This is one way to do it – every call will start a new session:

```
import uuid
boto3.client('lex-runtime').post_text(
    botName='mybot',
    botAlias = 'alphathree',
    userId=uuid.uuid4().hex,
    inputText="I want to order 5 gallons of ice cream")
```